# Mount SocketIO to FastAPI

Tags: python, socket.io, fastapi

I need to Mount my SocketIO Server to my FastAPI App on /socket.io, but when i try to use it it shows a 404 and can't find the Route.

```
def handle_connect(sid, environ):
    print(f"socket connected with sid {sid}")

class socketmanager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.server = socketio.AsyncServer(
            cors_allowed_origins=["http://localhost:30000", "http://localhost:40000"],
            async_mode="asgi",
            logger=True,
            engineio_logger=True,
        )
        self.app = socketio.ASGIApp(self.server)

    @property
    def on(self):
        return self.server.on

    @property
    def send(self):
        return self.server.send

    def mount_to(self, path: str, app):
        app.mount(path, self.app)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    socket_manager = socketmanager()
    socket_manager.on("connect", handler=handle_connect)

    app = FastAPI()
    socket_manager.mount_to("/socket.io", app)
    uvicorn.run(app, host="localhost", port=40000)

    @app.get("/")
    def index():
        return "response"
```

this is the smallest example of how my Server works.
How can i use a FastAPI mount on /socket.io without breaking the entire Routing?

I tried mounting on "/" instead and this works fine, but my unchangeable Frontend won't connect the Socket further than the HTTP Handshake.